# I wanna make a system form's column's data is required

Tags: python, django

username&email and sex&year&month&day can be registed in my app.I wrote in views.py

```
def regist_save(request):

    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'regist_form': regist_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form,
    }

    if request.method == "POST" and regist_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        try:
                username = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('username', None)
                email = regist_form.cleaned_data.get('email', None)

                user = User.objects.get(Q(username=username) | Q(email=email))

                messages.warning(request, 'That detailed use is already available.')

                return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
                regist = regist_form.save(commit=False)
                regist.is_staff = True
                regist.save()

                profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                profile.user = regist
                sex = request.POST.get("sex", "")

                profile.sex = sex
                profile.save()

                return render(request, 'registration/detail.html')
    else:
        print(regist_form.errors)
        print(profile_form.errors)
        return render(request, 'registration/regist.html', context)
```

in forms.py

```
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = NewUser
        fields = (
           "sex"
        )
```

in models.py

```
class NewUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

When I select sex ,write username& email and put REGIST button in browser, these data is registed.However,now if i do not select sex,the data is registed.I wanna make a system putting sex data forcibly, but current system is different.What is wrong in my code?Why is profile_form.is_valid() in views.py effective?How should i fix this?

Comment: For single item tuples add a comma: `fields = ("sex", )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By specifying `blank=True` in

```
sex = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True, blank=True, default=None)
```

you are telling Django that the `sex` field is optional in forms. Try removing that.